# Python / Tkinter keep window in back

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python with `Tkinter`, if you use the command:

```
`sometkapp.overrideredirect(True)`
```

It will make a `Tkinter` window that doesn't have a border from the window manager; however, at least on my windowing system, the `Tkinter` window then stays on top of all the other windows.

Is there a way to send a `Tkinter` window to the back, so that it always stays under all other open windows?

Answer (score 0):

In some system window manager decides which window is on top or on bottom.

Using `overrideredirect(True)` you resign with its services - on some systems this meen no drawing border, no moving on top/on bottom (probably no refreshing window), no sending events (key pressed, mouse move).

I think you can do nothing with this using Tkinter or even pure Python. Maybe other module could do something.